# Customize Material UI animations durations

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i'm using React Material UI v4, and i'd like to change transition duration for default animations ( collapse, ...etc )

i've used

```
MuiCollapse: {
    container: {
        transitionDelay: `1000ms !important`,
    },
},
```

it worked well, but it need (!important) which made me feel its not the best way,
also i want entering duration and exiting duration are different

Thanks
in createTheme

Answer (score 0):

You can override the corresponding [theme](https://v4.mui.com/customization/default-theme/#default-theme) props:

```js
import createTheme from 'material-ui/style/createTheme';

const theme = {
  transitions: {
    duration: {
      enteringScreen: 1000,
      leavingScreen: 1000
    }
  }
}

createTheme(theme);
```

Comment: unfoltunatelly it doesn't work, i understand it exists in theme object, 
my purpose is to change the duration of Collapse ( in and out )